# How do I get the args from a post or get with Python without using cgi.FieldStorage

Tags: python, webserver

I just read that cgi is deprecated and so cgi.FieldStorage will stop working.

I'm struggling to find the replacement for this functionality. All the searches I've tried refer to urllib or requests, both of which (AFAIK) are designed to create requests, not to respond to them.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reference to urllib is actually a bit misleading. The following might give some insight to the cgi interface from a python programmers point of view:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
'''
preflight_cgi.py
check the preflight option call
'''

import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Content-Type: text/html")    # HTML is following
    print() 
    i = 0
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print("argv{}: {}\n".format(i, arg))
    i = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print("line {}: {}\n".format(i, line))
        i += 1
           
    print("<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>")
    print("<H1>This is the environmet</H1>")
    for it in os.environ.items():
        print("<p>{} = {}</p>".format(it[0], it[1]))
```

Put that where your current cgi.FieldStorage based app is and call it via the address line of the browser.

You will see something like

[...]

CONTENT_LENGTH = 0

QUERY_STRING = par=meter&var=able

REQUEST_URI = /cgi-bin/preflight_cgi.py?par=meter&var=able

REDIRECT_STATUS = 200

SCRIPT_NAME = /cgi-bin/preflight_cgi.py

REQUEST_METHOD = GET

SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1

SERVER_SOFTWARE = lighttpd/1.4.53

GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1

REQUEST_SCHEME = http

SERVER_PORT = 80

[...]

The environment variables have already most of done.

As an alternative you can also use one of the http.server classes to build the server completely in python.

Comment: Uh, thanks - I'm familiar with the underlying mechanism but the whole point of libraries (like that FieldStorage stuff) is so that people don't have to write their own methods to extract stuff --- particularly for the REQUEST_URI header (or worse when it's a POST request).
So if the cgi library is going away (why?), surely something (better?) will replace it.

Comment: I'm running a large Wordpress site under apache2 - last thing with which I need to deal is running separate servers :-)

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.publisher/issues/39) has some information as to why the cgi library is deprecated, and it doesn't sound too optimistic about a quick replacement.

Obviously they think that it is enough, that 

urllib.parse.urlparse(os.environ['REQUEST_URI'])

will give you the same result (for GET requests).
:-((

Comment: Yeah -- the question for me then is how to deal with POST requests --- it's extremely odd to deprecate something without providing a replacement!

Comment: Getting data for a POST is not a big deal. You just have to read the stdin. What you get there is much the same as the environment variable QUERY_STRING in the example above

Comment: I don't get why people are making these suggestions.

I understand (quite deeply) how all this stuff works under the covers but I see no reason to have to go back to first principles when there are (or should be) suitable libraries that do this work for you (e.g. cgi.FieldStorage that has already done the work of reading from stdin, parsing the data, etc)  

It's like arguing that we have to use an assembler because the compiler is going away.